# poner un nav dentro de la cabecera

Tags: html, html5, css3, cabeceras-http

Tengo que hacer una pagina web con html y css, lo que necesito es que me expliquen o me ayuden con el codigo para poder ingresar una barra navegadora , que por ejemplo diga quienes somos inicio etc , en una imagen de cabecera que tengo, la  imagen es grande, de ancho ocupa todo el header, pero de alto, no es tan grande, la idea es como dejar esa imagen de fondo del nav

codigo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta content="span-es" http-equiv="Content-Language"/>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type"/>
  <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
  <title>tics</title>  
 </head>
 <body >
 <!-- Cabecera -->
   <header>
                            <div class ="logo">
      <img src="imagenes/cabecera.jpg" width="1349" height="500">
      <div class="texto-encima">Texto</div>
      <div class="centrado">Texto centrado</div>
       </div>

    <nav>
      <a href="#"> menu </a>
      <a href="#"> servicios </a>
      <a href="#"> proyectos</a>
      <a href="#"> contacto</a>
    </nav>


                
   </header>
```

La idea es poner ese nav dentro de la imagen "cabecera"

Comment: no has intentado usar la propiedad : background-image de CSS3?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos forma para poder hacerlo con la etiqueta `background-image`

1. la puedes declarar dentro del `nav`

```html
<nav style=" background-image: url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/76faf0ac8fc4d63e642321b1034f8970/tumblr_mxcznwtMez1r11qslo1_500.gif)">
     <a href="#"> menu </a>
     <a href="#"> servicios </a>
     <a href="#"> proyectos</a>
     <a href="#"> contacto</a>
</nav>
```

2. En un archivo ``css` a parte puedes declararla

```css
nav {
  background-image: url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/76faf0ac8fc4d63e642321b1034f8970/tumblr_mxcznwtMez1r11qslo1_500.gif)
}
```

```html
<nav>
     <a href="#"> menu </a>
     <a href="#"> servicios </a>
     <a href="#"> proyectos</a>
     <a href="#"> contacto</a>
</nav>
```

Despúes puedes agregar mas código `css` como `background-repeat: no-repeat;`, `background-position: center`, entre otros para arreglar la pocisión de la imagen.

También puedes visitar la siguiente página https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Espero sea lo que estás buscando, buen dia.